# Administration menu module not working

Tags: 7

Im using D7.24
I downloaded [admin_menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module (I tried also previous releases) but when trying to enable it I can't, and I get this info message in the description module field :

> Requires : System (>7.10) (is incompatible with version > 7.x-1.0-beta3) Required for : Administration menu Toolbar style (disabled)

I searched about this problem but I did not found anyone has this problem before!

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
This is the info that I get in status report :
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about issue in the admin menu module and you have to submit a bug in the module issue queue page.

Comment: I see no record of admin menu module version 7.x-1.0-beta3 - You should be on 7.x-3.0-rc4, can you confirm you admin menu module version?

Comment: @rooby: Im using the latest version of admin menu: 7.x-3.0-rc4.
This is strange! not :)

Comment: That's not strange, but the message "is incompatible with version > 7.x-1.0-beta3" is.

Comment: I would go and look to see if you have the admin module in another directory, eg, look in `modules` as well as `sites/all/modules` etc as it looks like you might have an old version in one directory that is getting picked up before the one you think should be found is actually found.

Comment: I don't think so, there is no other admin_menu module in my installation (neither in profile folders nor in /modules folder)...

Answer (score 2):

Per this line in admin_menu.info:

```
dependencies[] = system (>7.10)
```

The module requires a core version of Drupal greater than 7.10. Currently yours must be less than that.

Drupal core is currently at 7.26; you'd be wise to update ASAP, there have been a number of security updates in recent memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the image of status report, and it tell me that's drupal 7.24 !

Comment: Sorry I think I read your error message wrong (my French is a little rusty :) It seems to be saying that the version of Admin Menu you've got (1.0-beta3) is only compatible with Drupal core <7.10. If you download the latest version of admin menu (1.0-rc4) that error should disappear

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working also :( I downloaded the latest version of admin_menu, I cleared the cache, and I get the same message.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry but I'm out of ideas it might be worth checking the issue queue for the module in case you can find anything similar. Or try disabling _other_ contrib modules you have one by one to see if you can spot anything that's making it break. Always take a backup first, of course :)

Comment: Ok, I doubt also if there is  module breaking the admin_menu I'll try to disable them one by one ;)
anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah it's a long shot, but I can't imagine what would be stopping that. Maybe try to enable the module using Drush, just to rule out it being something wrong with the your Drupal install

Comment: Yes I thought about drush to force enabling it but no luck also, maybe like you said, there is something wrong in my installtion,
so I deleted the dependencies in .info file and it works like a charm ;-)

Comment: Awesome solution, wish I'd thought of that ;)

Comment: It's also a bandaid solution. There is obviously something not right about your installation so I would look at finding out why it was happening and fix that instead of just stopping the error message. It's like putting some tape over your car's check engine light and saying there is no problem because you can't see the light. - Be vary wary of bandaid fixes.